# Where I can find complete manual about style of dialog window?

Tags: android, dialog, styles

Where I can find complete manual about style of dialog window?
I've create custom dialog

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this, style);
```

As result i want to change background of title and buttons region(footer).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html) is the best way to know about dialogs.
Moreover, just browsing the web with the keywords android, dialog, custom, design should give some good results.

I don't really think there is the perfect manual about how to style a good dialog window.

Moreover, a dialog window is an android widget, so you can easily create a loyout using XML or directly in your code. The official documentation is still the best manual for that.